# Subloop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have posts in wordpress that looks like this
Category 'First'
2019 - Post 1
2019 - Post 2
2019- Post 3
2018 - Post1
2018 - Post 2

How to display something like this

**Category 'First'**

**2019**

Post 1

Post 2

Post3

**2018**

Post 1

Post 2

Right now, this is the code I have which renders the posts of a given category 'spectacle'.

```
           <?php
                $args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'post',
                'category_name'=>'spectacle',
                'posts_per_page'=> -1
              );

              $specQuery = new WP_Query ($args);

              while ($specQuery->have_posts()): $specQuery->the_post();
              ?>


              <div class="row porfolio-details">

                <div class="portfolio-image">

                <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
                <div class="caption">

                  <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="portfolio-text">
                <h6>
                  <?php the_content();?>
                </h6>
              </div>
              </div>
          <!--ENDS AND RESET THE LOOP-->
          <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

So how to loop over the category and through another argument, and that this argument only shows up once ?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code to this:

```
<?php
    $years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );
    foreach ( $years as $year ) {
    echo '<h2>' . $year->year . '</h2><ul>';

    $args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'category_name'=>'spectacle',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1
  );
  $specQuery = new WP_Query ($args);
  while ($specQuery->have_posts()): $specQuery->the_post();
?>
  <div class="row porfolio-details">
    <div class="portfolio-image">
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
    <div class="caption">
      <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-text">
    <h6>
      <?php the_content();?>
    </h6>
  </div>
  </div>
<!--ENDS AND RESET THE LOOP-->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It renders all the posts for every year. **2018** : post1, post2 **2017 : post1 : post2**. In the view, it seems like 2017 is a sublevel